# In WPF, How can I draw a rectangle over an image without fading the color and being transparent?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have an image control in WPF and want to create highlighting over the image without fading the color of the rectangle when you change the opacity. This is what I want it to look like:

[image]

But I'm getting this:

[image]

Here is the code I have now.

```
   <Grid>
       <Image 
            x:Name="img"
            Stretch="Uniform"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"
            UseLayoutRounding="True"
            Source="Images/Doc.bmp" />
        <Canvas>
            <Rectangle
                Width="300"
                Fill="Yellow"
                Opacity=".5"
                Height="100"
                Canvas.Top="200"
                Canvas.Left="100" />
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
```

What do I need to do to the rectangle to create the effect of the first image?

Comment: That can't work with a filled Rectangle on top of an Image. If you are able to turn the BMP into a PNG with transparent background, you may put the Rectangle behind the Image. Otherwise your only option is to modify the bitmap's pixel values.

Comment: Do you think this can be implemented in WPF? @Clemens  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22538140/highlight-effect-like-snipping-tool